# Sending text to PayPal Cart results in strange characters

Tags: jquery, html, string, text, paypal

I'm using the basic PayPal shopping cart (Website Payments Standard).

I have the following in my HTML as part of an item description:

```
<div class="block">
    <p>What&rsquo;s yours?</p>
    <!-- some other html -->
</div>
```

I then select this piece of text like this:

```
phrase = $('.block p:first').text();
```

I have also tried this:

```
phrase = $('.block p:first').html();
```

Then, before it's submitted, I copy it into the form like this:

```
$('#PayPalForm input[name=os1]').val(phrase);
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form id="PayPalForm" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="redacted" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="paypal_confirm.html" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="redacted" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="phrase" />
    <input type="hidden" name="os1" id="os1" value="" />
</form>
```

This is my HTML doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

This is my text encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

---

It's working. However, when the remotely hosted cart page opens (at PayPal), the phrase is displayed with non-sensical characters where an apostrophe should be.

```
phrase: Whatâ€™s yours?
```

At the very least I would have expected the raw `&rsquo;` to display rather than a `â€™`.

Why did this happen and what can I do to clean it up?

Comment: Forgive me, but why isn't the phrase simply part of the form to begin with?

Comment: @nachito, there is one form and many multiple ordering options which are only copied into the form as needed.  Not that unusual to do in a PayPal Website Payments Standard situation.  That's all beside the point though.  It's being copied into the form correctly in the first place, just not making it over to (or being displayed by) PayPal correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify the encoding of the information contained in your form: [Setting the Character Set – charset](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics).

```
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
```